# Eclipse not giving Import option to resolve an unknown reference

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I've been away from Eclipse for a long time and am having an issue getting a basic Selenium program working. Inside my main() I'm trying to declare a new Webdriver.

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver;
```

Of course this gives an error as I have not imported org.openqa.selenium.* yet. If I hovered over WebDriver in the past it used to give me the option of importing the required library. It's not doing so. I have no idea why. The selenium libraries are in my build path. I'm using Eclipse 2023 09.

Any help at resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The selenium libraries are in my build path.

You haven't given enough information to know which of a few problems you're dealing with.

#### 90%+ odds: No, they aren't.

Selenium isn't in your build path. Something else is, or it's not in there at all. If you have no idea how to proceed, write out the fully qualified package name or write the import by hand, and if it's still an error, it's definitely this.

#### Other option - hover isn't on

In the 'source' menu you'll find 'Organize Imports'. Have java code that is, other than missing `import` statements, completely valid, then pick that option. It'll appear. If it doesn't, it's the first thing (no, you don't have selenium on the project's classpath).

Alternatively, hit CTRL+1 or CMD+1 depending on OS (or if that is not working, open the preferences, type `keys` in the pref filter box, then in the key shortcut settings, type `quick fix`, and check out what it is. You may have changed it; CTRL+1/CMD+1 are merely defaults). This is more or less what the hover thing does. If this *does not* pop up a box that offers to import it, it's probably back to the first door.

#### Other option - you're editing a projectless java file

In eclipse you can create scratchpads or just open a random java file straight from disk. However, such files need to be self contained; they don't *have* a classpath and can't get one either. You'll know if the editor's icon is a document thingie with a J as usual, but the J is an outline (with white in the middle), instead of solid blue. If this is the case, open (or create) a source file inside a project.

Comment: If I open project properties and go to Build Path I can see the various Selenium jar files listed under Classpath. Java is listed under Modulepath. I can also see them in the tree view under Referenced libraries. Hover is on. If I enter the import command manually it tells me that the package is not accessible.

Comment: Also this may have something to do with running on a VMware session. I'm going to try this on my personal desktop and see if there's a difference.

Comment: Just double checking: Its `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` - note the parentheses. You did that, right?

Comment: Yes, I did, sorry I didn't include that here. It's not the VM either. I have the same issue on my personal desktop. I also have my CLASSPATH system environment variable set and it includes where the Selenium jar files are located. I should honestly just download IntelliJ, it was SO much easier. I've followed a few tutorials and they're doing the exact same thing I am but I don't get option to import the selenium library that they get on the hover.

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` sys env variable is obsolete and has no effect here in any case (conceptually it's completely broken: You can run more than one java app on a single computer, hence the idea of a global classpath variable is just wrong). You've misconfigured something, but you aren't giving us the details we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I switched to Visual Studio and C#. No more issues.